# Error in SQLite using empty insert statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given table and queries (SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE project (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name INTEGER DEFAULT 3)
Query 1: INSERT INTO project () VALUES ()
Query 2: INSERT INTO project (name) VALUES (1)
Query 3: INSERT INTO project (id) VALUES (5)
```

Executing the first query causes an error (`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ")": syntax error` in php), while the other two execute just fine - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8567a. Why does this error occur and why does it work fine for MySQL (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ae7f/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLite's implementation of INSERT grammar](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) is different from [MySQL implementation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html).

SQLite:

[image]

The `column-name` list cannot be empty.

MySQL:

> If both the column list and the VALUES list are empty, INSERT creates a row with each column set to its default value

Reading various versions of SQL standards favors MySQL interpretation. Example from 1992 version, more recent versions seem to be using more or less the same grammar and wording:

```
<insert columns and source> ::=
            [ <left paren> <insert column list> <right paren> ]
          <query expression>
          | DEFAULT VALUES
```

...

> If the
>               `<insert column list>` is omitted, then an `<insert column list>`
>               that identifies all columns of T in the ascending sequence of
>               their ordinal positions within T is implicit.

To get the desired result on SQLite, use

```
INSERT INTO tablename DEFAULT VALUES
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting to know, maybe you could add that `INSERT INTO project DEFAULT VALUES` would solve the issue (obtaining the desired effect)?